# Symfony 5 : Users still anonymous after login (sometimes)

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, symfony5

I'm using a custom authenticator and a custom user provider in **Symfony 5.0.10**

Some of my users have complained that they can't login anymore : in fact in some cases, **the login will be sucessful (onAuthenticationSuccess is called) but the user will still be anonymous.** This causes a direct redirection to login page.

**This is solved by clearing the cookies (PHPSESSID) or by using a private navigation window.** I can't explain how thats comes into the login logic of an anonymous user.

If you guys can find the issue that would really help me, i've been spending a few all nighters on this and can't figure it out.

Here is my code :

security.yaml

```
security:
    encoders:
        App\Security\User:
            algorithm: none

    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
    providers:
        # used to reload user from session & other features (e.g. switch_user)
        app_galette_user_provider:
            id: App\Security\GaletteUserProvider
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            anonymous: lazy
            provider: app_galette_user_provider
            logout:
                path: app_logout
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - App\Security\AppCustomAuthenticator
                # where to redirect after logout
                # target: app_any_route

            # activate different ways to authenticate
            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#firewalls-authentication

            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/impersonating_user.html
            # switch_user: true

    # Easy way to control access for large sections of your site
    # Note: Only the *first* access control that matches will be used
    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```

Custom Authenticator (AppCustomAuthenticator.php)

```
<?php

namespace App\Security;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\InvalidCsrfTokenException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UsernameNotFoundException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Csrf\CsrfToken;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Csrf\CsrfTokenManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Guard\Authenticator\AbstractFormLoginAuthenticator;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Guard\PasswordAuthenticatedInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Util\TargetPathTrait;

class AppCustomAuthenticator extends AbstractFormLoginAuthenticator implements PasswordAuthenticatedInterface
{
    private $urlGenerator;
    private $csrfTokenManager;
    private $passwordEncoder;

    public function __construct(UrlGeneratorInterface $urlGenerator, UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder)
    {
        $this->urlGenerator = $urlGenerator;
        $this->passwordEncoder = $passwordEncoder;
    }

    public function supports(Request $request)
    {
        return 'app_login' === $request->attributes->get('_route') && $request->isMethod('POST');
    }

    public function getCredentials(Request $request)
    {
        $credentials = [
            'username' => $request->request->get('email'),
            'password' => $request->request->get('password'),
            //'csrf_token' => $request->request->get('_csrf_token'),
        ];

        $request->getSession()->set(
            Security::LAST_USERNAME,
            $credentials['username']
        );

        return $credentials;
    }

    public function supportsRememberMe()
    {
        return false;
    }

    public function getUser($credentials, UserProviderInterface $userProvider)
    {
        // Load / create our user however you need.
        // You can do this by calling the user provider, or with custom logic here.
        try {
            $user = $userProvider->loadUserByUsername($credentials['username']);
        } catch (UsernameNotFoundException $e) {
            throw new CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException("Erreur lors de la connexion : veuillez vérifier vos identifiants et l'état de votre cotisation.");
        }

        if (!$user) {
            // fail authentication with a custom error
            throw new CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException('Email could not be found.');
        }

        return $user;
    }

    public function checkCredentials($credentials, UserInterface $user)
    {
        if ($credentials['password'] === $user->getPassword()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Used to upgrade (rehash) the user's password automatically over time.
     */
    public function getPassword($credentials): ?string
    {
        return $credentials['password'];
    }

    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, $providerKey)
    {
        return new RedirectResponse($this->urlGenerator->generate('index'));
    }

    protected function getLoginUrl()
    {
        return $this->urlGenerator->generate("app_login");
    }
}
```

And my User.php entity :

```
<?php

namespace App\Security;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\EquatableInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

class User implements UserInterface, EquatableInterface
{

    private $id;
    private $email;
    private $roles;
    private $password;
    private $nom;
    private $prenom;
    private $adresse;
    private $adresse2;
    private $cp;
    private $ville;
    private $pays;
    private $tel;
    private $gsm;
    private $salt;
    private $username;

    public function isEqualTo(UserInterface $user)
    {

        if ($this->getUsername() !== $user->getUsername()) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId(): int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @param int $id
     */
    public function setId($id): void
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getNom(): string
    {
        return $this->nom;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $nom
     */
    public function setNom($nom): void
    {
        $this->nom = $nom;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPrenom(): string
    {
        return $this->prenom;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $prenom
     */
    public function setPrenom($prenom): void
    {
        $this->prenom = $prenom;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAdresse(): string
    {
        return $this->adresse;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $adresse
     */
    public function setAdresse($adresse): void
    {
        $this->adresse = $adresse;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAdresse2(): ?string
    {
        return $this->adresse2;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $adresse2
     */
    public function setAdresse2($adresse2): void
    {
        $this->adresse2 = $adresse2;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCp(): ?string
    {
        return $this->cp;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $cp
     */
    public function setCp($cp): void
    {
        $this->cp = $cp;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getVille(): ?string
    {
        return $this->ville;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $ville
     */
    public function setVille($ville): void
    {
        $this->ville = $ville;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPays(): ?string
    {
        return $this->pays;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $pays
     */
    public function setPays($pays): void
    {
        $this->pays = $pays;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTel(): ?string
    {
        return $this->tel;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $tel
     */
    public function setTel($tel): void
    {
        $this->tel = $tel;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getGsm(): ?string
    {
        return $this->gsm;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $gsm
     */
    public function setGsm($gsm): void
    {
        $this->gsm = $gsm;
    }

    public function getEmail(): ?string
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function setEmail(string $email): self
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * A visual identifier that represents this user.
     *
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getUsername(): string
    {
        return $this->username;
    }

    public function setUsername(string $username): self
    {
        $this->username = $username;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getRoles(): array
    {
        $roles = $this->roles;
        // guarantee every user at least has ROLE_USER
        $roles[] = 'ROLE_USER';

        return array_unique($roles);
    }

    public function setRoles(array $roles): self
    {
        $this->roles = $roles;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getPassword(): string
    {
        return (string) $this->password;
    }

    public function setPassword(string $password): self
    {
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getSalt()
    {
        return;
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
        // If you store any temporary, sensitive data on the user, clear it here
        // $this->plainPassword = null;
    }

}

'''

-> I'm not including my custom user provider as i know it to work (it correctly returns the user)
-> My user passwords are indeed "in clear", this is a very specific scenario which poses no security threat
```

Answer (score 1):

This may be caused by symfony session fixation protection.
It is enabled by default and should refresh session id after user authentication. More info [in symfony docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html#session-fixation-strategy)

Check if the PHPSESSID cookie refreshes after EVERY request.
If it does, then your authenticator triggers [this method](https://github.com/symfony/security-http/blob/master/Session/SessionAuthenticationStrategy.php#L43) refreshing session id on each user request.
Which leads to the following: if the user makes second request before they receive the response from the previous, their session id becomes invalid, and they become unauthenticated.

You can of course disable this protection in your security config:

```
security:
    session_fixation_strategy: none
```

but better is to fix the problem and do not create a vulnerability in your system.

Comment: Sadly i tried to update my config with session_fixation_strategy: none and it changed nothing. Upon further inspectionit appeared that even before that config update, the PHPSESSID was **not** updated every session. Should it be the default Symfony behavior ?

Comment: Session id should be updated only once: after the authentication, not on every request. So your authenticator is working OK. Then the issue is somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks for the input, i'll try to test on another server to see if something's wrong with my PHP config...